# Error: conflicting types for a function

Tags: c, function

Below is the `insertItem()` declaration in `list.h`,

`void insertItem(List *, void *newItem);`

Below is the `insertItem()` declaration in `tree.h`,

`void insertItem(Tree *, void *item);`

---

Below is the `Tree` abstraction, that re-use `List` abstraction, by saying `#include"list/list.h"`

```
#ifndef TREE_H /* Header guard */
#define TREE_H

#include"list/list.h"

.....

void insertItem(Tree *, void *item);
....

#endif
```

---

On compilation:

`gcc -Wall -g -I. -DARRAY -DMULTI_WALK ./list/*.c ./tree/*.c testTree.c -o testTree`

Below is the error:

```
./tree/tree.h:50:6: error: conflicting types for ‘insertItem’
 void insertItem(Tree *, void *item);
      ^
In file included from ./tree/tree.h:8:0,
                 from ./tree/multiWalkImpl.c:2:
./list/list.h:35:7: note: previous declaration of ‘insertItem’ was here
  void insertItem(List *, void *newItem);
```

---

What is the nature of problem? Because `insertItem()` in `tree.h` & `list.h` have different parameter types.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C has no function overloading, conflicts like this are usually solved by adding a prefix describing the differing parameter.

e.g. `List_insertItem` and `Tree_insertItem`.

---

Note that in real code, this kind of namespacing prefixes should be added before any such conflicts arise, because there's no way of knowing beforehand what function names the user code is using. This saves the trouble of breaking existing code when the names are later changed.

Comment: Plus one, No other alternative? A function `f`, if it has different argument types and return types, then, Can we declare multiple `f`?

Comment: No, C has no function overloading. This is how it's usually done.

Comment: Unlike C++, there is no polymorphism in C. You can not have two functions with the same name but different signatures. It is a good practice to prefix all the functions dealing with the type in the same way, e.g. list_insert(), list_delete(), list_count(), and so on. Same for tree_insert(), tree_delete(), ...

Comment: @MikeBessonov This is not polymorphism, this is [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).

Comment: @MikeBessonov To implement polymorphism in C, you atleast need function pointer. Do you think am trying to be polymorphic?

Comment: Now, this change is really painful for me, because am using `List` in `Stack` ,`Queue` and `Tree`

Comment: @tuple_cat I have done the changes, as you recommend, shown [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150830/tree-abstraction-code-structure)

Answer (score 2):

In your case you could use the _Generic operator.

First you need to change the names of your container functions. Preferably to something like: list_insertItem, tree_insertItem, etc..

Then use generic:

```
#define insertItem( object , item )    _Generic( object ,                 \
                                                 Tree*: tree_insertItem , \
                                                 List*: list_insertItem )( object , item )
```

This macro definition must see definitions of both types and both function so your could put it into a common header that includes both headers for containers, include that header in your code, and use the generic macro function.

Comment: I don't understand this syntax. What is _generic operator? Is it something other than C, like C++?

Comment: @overexchange It's C11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic.

Comment: @tuple_cat Where should I keep this _Generic code, sepearate header file outside `list.h` & `tree.h`. BTW, you inject symbol names at multiple places.?

Comment: @overexchange Yup, for example.

Comment: As per the above code, `inserItem()` is only for the user of `List`abstraction. and that new header file has nothing to do with `List` abstraction. Is that correct?

Comment: @overexchange Yes.

Comment: @2501 in this [code](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/tree/master/code), where to inject  your code? in `code` folder as a separate header file?

Comment: @overexchange The header can be anywhere, as long as the _Generic operator sees the definitions of all the types and functions used in it.

Comment: @2501 What is the advantage of doing this? Is it that, User is blindfolded with the implementation detail, when using `Tree` & `List`? or any other use? Syntax looks like a python runtime(dictionares of dictionaries)?

Comment: @overexchange I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131446/discussion-between-overexchange-and-2501).